Absorption and scattering coefficient vs. Material subsurface properties
I did not find any information yet about the link between the subsurface parameters in the material properties (method, weight, radius, scale and anisotropy) and the physical equations explaining the subsurface scattering with parameters like refraction index, scattering coefficient and absorption coefficient. For a project I would like to understand the parallel between material measurements and how to render it in Blender accurately. Any help would be helpful ! Thank you very much!
